# Chrome Browser Not supported is visible when open using selenium webdriver . Whereas same URL works when open directly in chrome

Tags: selenium, browser, webdriver

I try to open an application using webdriver code but getting Browser doesn't support. where as same url I can open directly

checked about::config to check the difference both the windows

13 June 2019
17:22

Normal chrome window:

> Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
>   Revision  78e4f8db3ce38f6c26cf56eed7ae9b331fc67ada-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#1013}
>   OS    Windows 10 OS Build 17134.706 JavaScript    V8 7.4.288.28
>   Flash 32.0.0.207 C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\PepperFlash\32.0.0.207\pepflashplayer.dll User Agent Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36 Command Line   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin
>   --flag-switches-end Executable Path   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe Profile
>   Path  C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

## Variations  d01ab0d3-ca7d8d80

Webdriver window

> Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
>   Revision  78e4f8db3ce38f6c26cf56eed7ae9b331fc67ada-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#1013}
>   OS    Windows 10 OS Build 17134.706 JavaScript    V8 7.4.288.28
>   Flash 24.0.0.189 internal-not-yet-present User Agent  Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36 Command Line   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir21628_16208\internal"
>   --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir21628_14652" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end data:, Executable Path    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   Profile
>   Path  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir21628_14652\Default

After Modification:

> Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
>   Revision  78e4f8db3ce38f6c26cf56eed7ae9b331fc67ada-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#1013}
>   OS    Windows 10 OS Build 17134.706 JavaScript    V8 7.4.288.28
>   Flash 32.0.0.207 C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\PepperFlash\32.0.0.207\pepflashplayer.dll User Agent Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36 Command Line   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-background-networking --disable-bundled-ppapi-flash --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir40376_20418\internal"
>   --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --ppapi-flash-path="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\32.0.0.207\pepflashplayer.dll"
>   --ppapi-flash-version=32.0.0.207 --remote-debugging-port=0 --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir40376_6930" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end data:, Executable Path    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   Profile
>   Path  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir40376_6930\Default

After modification the code I was getting the proper flash version but the issue still remains same

Comment: Have you tried without adding the `extension`?

Comment: Which extension needs to be added